# How to create a Jandex index for RESTeasy Multipart Provider

Tags: java, jax-rs, multipartform-data, resteasy, quarkus

I'm trying to use RESTeasy Multipart with Quarkus, but when I do
`mvn clean compile quarkus:dev`

I get this warning:
`Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:
- org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput`

I tried all of these solutions: [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module) but none of them work, I still get the same warning.

Quarkus Version: 0.15
The goal is to upload a file.

This is the part of the Code which uses
`import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart;`
`import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput;`

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/fileupload")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    //@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
        System.out.println("TEST TEST TEST");
        final String UPLOADED_FILE_PATH = "/tmp";

        String fileName = "";

        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("uploadedFile");

        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {

            try {

                MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
                fileName = getFileName(header);

                //convert the uploaded file to inputstream
                InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,null);

                byte [] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

                //constructs upload file path
                fileName = UPLOADED_FILE_PATH + fileName;

                writeFile(bytes,fileName);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return Response.status(201)
                .entity("uploadFile is called, Uploaded file name : " + fileName).build();

    }

    /**
     * header sample
     * {
     *  Content-Type=[image/png],
     *  Content-Disposition=[form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.extension"]
     * }
     **/
    //get uploaded filename, is there a easy way in RESTEasy?
    private String getFileName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> header) {

        String[] contentDisposition = header.getFirst("Content-Disposition").split(";");

        for (String filename : contentDisposition) {
            if ((filename.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {

                String[] name = filename.split("=");

                String finalFileName = name[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
                return finalFileName;
            }
        }
        return "unknown";
    }

    //save to somewhere
    private void writeFile(byte[] content, String filename) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(filename);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        fop.write(content);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();

    }
```

This is the pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example.comcord.asset</groupId>
  <artifactId>assetProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.version>0.15.0</quarkus.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>27.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>native-image</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t worry, it’s not an issue and you can safely ignore the message.

We have an ignore list in Quarkus and I will add this one to the list as it’s not something that is either serialized or deserialized. The message is specifically for classes that will be used by a JSON/XML... serializer.

It should be fixed in the next release planned for Wednesday. I’ll open a PR tomorrow.