# It is possible to read an annotation (for example @Scheduled) from a lib?

Tags: quarkus

I start by saying that I am a beginner with Quarkus, and I do not have an advanced knowledge on CDI.
I would like to know if it is possible to tell to quarkus, in my main project, to read annotations used in another project and imported as library. In particularly, I would like to have a library that define how a class should be execute cyclically (with @Scheduled annotation) and providing an interface. Then, I would like to define this class in my main project implementing the interface, and provide as a bean using the annotation @ApplicationScoped @Alternative.

Is this is possible to achieve ?

Currently, trying the approach explain just before, the annotations in my libs are ignored.

Comment: Does the library have a `beans.xml` file or a Jandex index?

Comment: No, and looking at the [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#limitations) it seems that the beans.xml is ignored.

Comment: It's definitely not ignored, and the guide doesn't say that. BTW this answer should actually answer this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/742081