# Quarkus cant find third party clasess for Jandex index even with jandex plugin and an empty META-INF/beans.xml

Tags: hibernate, orm, quarkus

Victor from Chile.

I have a quarkus application and I want to use quarkus-hibernate-orm for Oracle database, but my Entities classes are in a third party jar, so I just put the dependency in the pom (of entities classes) below of quarkus-hibernate-orm dependency and of course the other quarkus dependencies as well.

I tried this:
[How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module)

The jandex plugin and beans.xml solutions doesnt work for me (I dont tried the third options but seems to work for another people the first two options that already tried.)

Testing with quarkus 0.20.0 and 0.19.1 and show me the same error.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cl.myproj</groupId>
    <artifactId>reposirorio-myproj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <quarkus.version>0.19.1</quarkus.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <docker-plugin.version>0.28.0</docker-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing: -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cl.entities</groupId>
            <artifactId>libMyEntities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!-- the parameters=true option is critical so that RESTEasy works fine -->
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- you need this specific version to integrate with the other build helpers -->
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- This is what injects the magic Quarkus bytecode -->
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Optionally activate this profile to compile the demo into native! -->
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>native-image</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemProperties>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                    </systemProperties>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>eclipse</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <!-- This is a trick to have the profile automatically activated by Eclipse -->
                    <name>m2e.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                    <pluginExecutions>
                                        <pluginExecution>
                                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>
                                                    docker-maven-plugin
                                                </artifactId>
                                                <versionRange>
                                                    [0.28.0,)
                                                </versionRange>
                                                <goals>
                                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <action>
                                                <ignore></ignore>
                                            </action>
                                        </pluginExecution>
                                    </pluginExecutions>
                                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

When a `make mvn clean install -DskipTests` (for skip tests) the console output says this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.440 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-02T12:53:29-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.19.1:build (default) on project reposirorio-compromiso: Failed to build a runnable JAR: Failed to build a runner jar: Failed to augment application classes: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.ConfigurationError: Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following JPA classes as they are not in the Jandex index:
[ERROR]     - org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable
[ERROR]     - org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable
[ERROR] Consider adding them to the index either by creating a Jandex index for your dependency via the Maven plugin, an empty META-INF/beans.xml or quarkus.index-dependency properties.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I espected build succesfull.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating this response knowing the question was not completely correct.

I understood is not an hibernate-orm error or "like jpa problem". In this case the error always was: "Cant find spring classes":

```
[ERROR]     - org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable
[ERROR]     - org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable
```

And not "Cant up the hibernate libraries, etc..." So the correct answer to my question is, use the method of this page: How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module. (like our partner Guillaume says!) but, to put the Spring classes into the index. (Spring are dependency of the Entities dependency of my proj.)

Just configured my application.properties like this:

quarkus.index-dependency.springd.group-id=org.springframework.data
quarkus.index-dependency.springd.artifact-id=spring-data-commons

And the result was:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.878 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-02T16:02:14-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cause I just found this classes in that jar (org.springframework.data) in a mvn repo search, So just work as expected.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not too sure Spring Data will work with Quarkus. We have our own layer called Panache.

To solve the error you have, you need to create an index for the Spring Data artifact containing the two classes mentioned.

You can do that using the `quarkus.index-dependency` method described in my answer here: [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module).