# Quarkus dependency injection failing with bean from Gradle Library Module

Tags: gradle, dependency-injection, shared-libraries, multi-module, quarkus

I´m trying to get dependency injection working in my multi-module project where I want to inject a bean from a library module. However, it´s failing because it cannot find the bean.

project root **settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'io.quarkus' version "${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}

include ':service-module'
include ':library-module'
```

service-module **build.gradle**

Tried compile, as well as implementation

```
dependencies {
   compile project(":library-module")
// implementation project(":library-module")
}
```

Bean from **library-module**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class LibraryBean {

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

**service-module** where injection happens

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Application {

    @Inject
    LibraryBean libraryBean;

}
```

**Stacktrace**

> Unsatisfied dependency for type com.mylibrary.LibraryBean and
>   qualifiers [@Default]
>           - java member: com.myservice.Application#LibraryBean
>           - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.myservice.Application, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any],
>   target=com.myservice.Application]

I´m not sure if this issue is Quarkus-related or a general problem that exists with CDI and Gradle modules.

How can I make the DI working accross modules?

Comment: Do you have a `beans.xml` file in your library module? See this question/answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/742081

Comment: @Ladicek oh dear, thank you very much. I´ve added an empty bean.xml into the META-INF/ directory of my library and it is working now

Comment: Good! Let me copy my comment as an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `beans.xml` file in your library module? See this question/answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/742081