# Quarkus - Unable to inject a RestClient for an interface defined in a separate jar within a multi-module project

Tags: quarkus

I have a multi-module project setup. I am able to use `@RestClient` based injections for interfaces that are part of the same module (and registered with the `@RegisterRestClient` annotation).

E.g.,

```
my-project
    |
    |- module-1
        src/main/java/mypackage
            RestAPIInterface.java
        src/test/java/
            @Inject @RestClient RestAPIInterface -- works
    |
    |- module-2
        src/main/java/myOtherPackage
            SomeBean.java
                @Inject @RestClient RestAPIInterface -- does not work
```

Do I need to enable any specific features / switches in order to get this working?

Comment: Do you have a `beans.xml` in your second module, or otherwise generate a Jandex index for it? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/742081

Comment: Hi Ladicek. Beans.xml files are already in place. I'm seeing this problem when running the test cases for module 2. Would you like a sample project to see this behavior?

Comment: Could you try with 1.3.0.Alpha2? It looks similar to some class loading issues we solved.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet, I tried it with the 1.3.0.Alpha2 version as well and still hitting the same problem. I have put together a simple project that show cases this problem. https://github.com/roguexz/quarkus-sample . If you can have a look at that let me know your findings, that would great!

Comment: I'll try and take a look tomorrow

Comment: [Harsha R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543349/harsha-r): just add an empty **beans.xml** under module-1 **resources/META-INF**. This lets Quarkus discover all beans/classes in this module.