# Load resources from dependency

Tags: maven, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application (lets name it cosmicApp) with working rest endpoints. I added a maven dependency which has some classes annotated with `@Path` and `@GET`. But these resources are not available when the application is running. Classes in the cosmicApp use classes in the added dependency, so it should be there.
Just the resources missing.
Any hint?

Both projects use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Quarkus version 1.2.1.Final

Comment: The dependency needs to be indexed, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/742081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to somehow register your resources from dependency. One possible option is to provide configuration parameters in config.properties to determine artifacts that should be included in the dependency context:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.<name>.group-id=<your dependency group ID>
quarkus.index-dependency.<name>.artifact-id=<your dependency artifact ID>
```

You can also use beans.xml or Jandex index. Please refer to the documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference