# Quarkus Builder Error The class java.lang.Enum is not inside the Jandex index

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a dependency which is indexed using jandex plugin, as explained by Guilhaume Smet answer to this question: [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module)

It worked fine, then I decided to use the extension **hibernate-orm-panache**. As soon as I add it to the pom, I get the followeing error:

```
    Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.5.2.Final:build (default) on project ####: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
   [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.deployment.PanacheHibernateResourceProcessor#validate threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: The class java.lang.Enum is not inside the Jandex index
    (...)
    Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: The class java.lang.Enum is not inside the Jandex index
        
        [ERROR]     at io.quarkus.panache.common.deployment.JandexUtil.isSubclassOf(JandexUtil.java:348)
        [ERROR]     at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.deployment.PanacheHibernateResourceProcessor.validate(PanacheHibernateResourceProcessor.java:177)  
        [ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        [ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        [ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        [ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        [ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:932)
```

Is that a bug ? Is there any turnaround?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it looks like a bug or at least an unexpected behavior that we need to fix.

Could you open an issue on our tracker with a simple reproducer?

We have until Wednesday July 1st evening to fix issues for 1.6.0.Final so the earlier we get the reproducer, the better. Thanks!