# quarkus - javax.persistence.AttributeConverter not in jandex index

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus, maven-module, jandex

I have a problem that seems to be very similar to [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module) and I carefully followed all suggested steps (jandex maven plugin, empty beans.xml, indexing other dependencies). However quarkus still complains:

```
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor#defineJpaEntities threw an exception: io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.ConfigurationError: Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following JPA classes as they are not in the Jandex index:
    - javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
```

An obvious difference to the above cited question is that quarkus does not find a third party class in my case, so I tried 'indexing other dependencies'. However, javax.persistence.AttributeConverter is part of maven module javax.persistence-api, which I do not depend on directly (but indirectly via another dependency to one of my own maven modules). So when I try 'indexing other dependencies' with

```
    quarkus.index-dependency.javax_persistence.group-id=javax.persistence
    quarkus.index-dependency.javax_persistence.artifact-id=javax.persistence-api
```

in my application.properties quarkus refuses with

```
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.index.ApplicationArchiveBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve artifact javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api::jar among the runtime dependencies of the application
```

I'm running out of ideas. Anything I am missing? Any ideas are highly appreciated.

I'm using quarkus version 1.7.0.

**edit - here is some of the code I use:**

entity class

```
package de.ruu.app.secmngmnt.jpa;

import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.MERGE;
import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbTransient;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import de.ruu.app.secmngmnt.ManagedRole;
import de.ruu.app.secmngmnt.RoleValue;
import de.ruu.lib.jpa.BaseEntity;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name="role")
public class ManagedRoleJPA extends BaseEntity implements ManagedRole
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "role", unique = true)
    @Convert(converter = RoleConverter.class)
    private RoleValue roleValue;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE })
    private Set<ManagedUserJPA> users = new HashSet<>();

    protected ManagedRoleJPA() { }

    public ManagedRoleJPA(RoleValue roleValue)
    {
        this();
        this.roleValue = roleValue;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonbTransient
    public Set<ManagedUserJPA> getUsers() { return users; }

    @Override public RoleValue getRoleValue() { return roleValue; }
}
```

attribute converter class

```
package de.ruu.app.secmngmnt.jpa;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

import de.ruu.app.secmngmnt.RoleValue;

/** converts {@link RoleValue} values to lowercase {@link String} values and back */
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class RoleConverter implements AttributeConverter<RoleValue, String>
{
    @Override public String convertToDatabaseColumn(RoleValue role) { return role.name().toLowerCase(); }

    @Override public RoleValue convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData)
    {
        return RoleValue.fromString(dbData);
    }
}
```

RoleValue class

```
package de.ruu.app.secmngmnt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public enum RoleValue
{
    ROOT ,
    ADMIN,
    USER
    ;

//  public String getName() { return name(); }

    public static RoleValue fromString(String string)
    {
        return
                Stream
                        .of(RoleValue.values())
                        .filter(role -> role.name().equals(string))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow
                        (
                                () -> new IllegalArgumentException("no " + RoleValue.class.getName() + " value matching " + string)
                        );
    }

    public final static List<String> buildStringList(List<RoleValue> roles)
    {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        roles.forEach(role -> result.add(role.name()));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * For use in annotations hard coded string constants that are available at compile time already are necessary.
     * Therefore it is no option to assign values that are calculated at runtime as in {@code
     * public static String ROOT = RoleValue.Root.getName();}
     */
    public static interface Values
    {
        public static String ROOT  = "ROOT" ;
        public static String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
        public static String USER  = "USER" ;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I can provide more relevant information.

Comment: Could you give more details about how you're using `AttributeConverter` in your entities? I think it's something we need to fix in Quarkus but I would need more information to do that.

Comment: I don't see any code? Can you update you question maybe? Or even create an issue in our tracker https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues ? Thanks!

Comment: There you are. I forgot that comments have space limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should ignore the `javax.persistence` interfaces when we are registering the entity hierarchy for reflection.

I created the following PR https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/11554 to fix it.