# How to write a Camel Quarkus extension for a Camel component/endpoint?

Tags: routes, apache-camel, quarkus, endpoint, eai

I have an own **camel component/endpoint** that I used successfully in many *routes* in a *Spring Boot App*.
I am trying to migrate to **camel quarkus** and use the same *routes* in my application.

It's not possible to use this **component/endpoint** in my **camel-quarkus aplication** by simply adding the related dependency: **quarkus** is not able to discover this **component/endpoint** as does **Spring Boot**.

The obvious solution is to write a **quarkus extension** that uses this **camel-component** under the hood: **quarkus [extensions](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/main/extensions/)** like [jdbc](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/main/extensions/jdbc), [file](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/main/extensions/file), [sql](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/tree/main/extensions/sql) and so on are implemented using the corresponding **[camel-components](https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/tree/master/components)**.

If we take a look into the [pom-xml of sql](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/blob/main/extensions/sql/pom.xml) of its runtime module, we find that it's using the equivalent [camel-sql component](https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/tree/master/components/camel-sql):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My problem is that quarkus still not discover the component/endpoint even if building by project (I am using eclipse), quarkus shows that it has installed my extension.
I searched for a long time in the internet but didn't find any helpfull source.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to use a custom or third party Camel component on Quarkus?

Comment: [James Netherton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8627215/james-netherton) : thank you for your enquiry. I have meanwhile found a solution that I will add as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution is **not to write** an extra extension.
The Quarkus-Runtime discovers the classes in a module or a third-party dependency if and only if:

1. the third-party dependency is indexed in the host-project:
   By adding the following entries to the **.properties** file:

quarkus.index-dependency..group-id=<group-id>
quarkus.index-dependency..artifact-id=<artifact-id>

or **.yaml** file:

```
quarkus:  
   index-dependency:
     <name>:
        group-id: <group-id>
        artifact-id: <artifact-id>
```

where <group-id> and <artifact-id> are third-party ones.

1. The [jandex-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.jandex/jandex-maven-plugin/1.1.0) is present in the *pom.xml* of this module or third-party dependency
2. An empty **beans.xml** is present under
   *src/main/resorces/META-INF* of this module/dependency

I find the answer to my question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/).

Answer (score 0):

use this dependencies . all quarkus dependecies starts with group id is org.apache.camel.quarkus and artifact  camel-quarkus-xxx

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-quarkus-sql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for postgresql

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```