# @WebFilter in maven dependency not being picked up by Quarkus

Tags: maven, servlet-filters, quarkus

I have a servlet filter declared using the @WebFilter annotation which is not being picked up by Quarkus. To make sure servlet filters actually works with Quarkus I created a second filter within the Quarkus application itself and it is working as expected.

How can I get a servlet filter that resides within a maven dependency to work in Quarkus?

Comment: Does the Maven dependency contain a Jandex index? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by @ladicek solved the problem - In my case what worked for me was to configure application.properties

```
quarkus.index-dependency.<name>.group-id=my-group
quarkus.index-dependency.<name>.artifact-id=my-artifact
```

[How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module)