# javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException:Unsatisfied dependency for type com.test.model.TestService and qualifiers [@Default] in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, gradle-plugin

I have created Quarkus project and added a SpringBoot project dependency in build.gradle file, dependency downloaded successfully.
Now when I am trying to inject a class which is available in dependancy, the build is getting failed.

**Note: The Class which I am trying to inject does not have @ApplicationScope annotation.**

getting below error:
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.test.model.TestService and qualifiers [@Default]

Comment: Does the dependency have a `beans.xml` file, or a Jandex index? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module for more.

Comment: Are you using spring in your project?, is TestService a bean ?, provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example otherwise its quite difficult to know the cause of your issue, which may come from different sources. But basically means that your service is not a managed bean or you have more than one a CDI does not know how to select the correct

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference

See the section 1 in the document above about creating the bean archive.
What worked for me is adding references to the dependencies in my application.properties.

```
quarkus.index-dependency.[name].group-id=[group]
quarkus.index-dependency.[name].artifact-id=[artifact]
```

For instance, in my project I injected some OpenTracing beans, ended up with:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.opentracing.group-id=io.opentracing
quarkus.index-dependency.opentracing.artifact-id=opentracing-api
```