# Quarkus + Kogito build error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find class info in jandex index for java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, kogito, jandex

I have a multi-module Maven project that uses Quarkus and Kogito, with MongoDb persistence.
The module with the Kogito process definition is using beans from another module.
One of the beans has a property of type `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

```
public class SomeBean {
    ...
    private LocalDateTime changeDatetime;

    public SomeBean() {
    }

    ...
    public LocalDateTime getChangeDatetime() {
        return changeDatetime;
    }

    public void setChangeDatetime(LocalDateTime changeDatetime) {
        this.changeDatetime = changeDatetime;
    }
}
```

When running a `@QuarkusTest` for a process, I get the following error:

```
io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.ProcessesAssetsProcessor#postGenerationProcessing threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while generating proto for model class com.example.PrcessInputBean Cannot find class info in jandex index for java.time.LocalDateTime
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.generate(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:143)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.protoOfDataClasses(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:52)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.PersistenceGenerator.generateProtoMarshaller(PersistenceGenerator.java:278)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.PersistenceGenerator.internalGenerate(PersistenceGenerator.java:179)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.core.AbstractGenerator.generate(AbstractGenerator.java:69)
       ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find class info in jandex index for java.time.LocalDateTime
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:159)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:51)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.internalGenerate(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:167)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:163)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:51)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.internalGenerate(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:167)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:163)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:51)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.internalGenerate(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:167)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:163)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:51)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.internalGenerate(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:167)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:163)
        at org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.JandexProtoGenerator.messageFromClass(JandexProtoGenerator.java:51)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.internalGenerate(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:167)
        at org.kie.kogito.codegen.process.persistence.proto.AbstractProtoGenerator.generate(AbstractProtoGenerator.java:136)
        ... 18 more
```

I tried solutions from: [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module)
but it does not work.

I noticed that if I remove the `java.time.LocalDateTime` property from the bean, the test is running fine.
How can I configure Jandex to index `java.time.LocalDateTime` and get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

support for `java.time.LocalDateTime` has been added to Kogito recently and will be available in the next release, 1.18.0.Final, see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-6756