# Is there a way to register a JAX-RS Provider in Quarkus application.properties?

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

I'm trying to register a class that implements `javax.ws.rs.core.Feature` in my Quarkus application. I understand that using `@Provider` annotation on the class should do it but this class is contained in an external jar so that's not an option. I want to avoid having to extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` and return my `Feature` implementation from `getClasses()`. Is there a property I can set in `application.properties` to register this `Feature` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.
However, you can make Quarkus look for `@Provider` classes in the external JAR. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224) for more details

Comment: The external JAR has a META-INF/beans.xml file. Indexing isn't the issue.