# my rest easy filter in a extension runtime is not discovered

Tags: quarkus

I have a custom quarkus extension from where I want to provide a resteasy request filter like below

```
@Provider
public class ReqFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
    }
}
```

I have this class in my runtime module, but it is not discovered or configured in reasteasy requests in integration-test project

Please let me know how to provide @Provider to resteasy

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/prasenjit-net/quarkus-extension-poc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions are not indexed automatically.

See [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module) for ways to index them.

When using `quarkus-resteasy`, in order to have your extension register a provider, you can generate `ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem`.

Comment: yes i already came across before, but what I am looking for is a way to selectively expose classes like its done the way its done in an extension. Same as AdditionalBeanBuildItem dose to expose a bean.

Comment: Answer updated.