# Build error - jandex index not found for java.time.OffsetDateTime

Tags: quarkus, kogito, jandex

I have a multi-module Maven project that uses Quarkus and Kogito, with MongoDb persistence. The module with the Kogito process definition is using beans from another module. One of the beans has a property of type java.time.OffsetDateTime

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be related with the location of the beans, when you have additional modules containing CDI beans, entities, objects serialized as JSON, you need to explicitly index them. Here you can find different ways to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723

Answer (score 0):

There is been some improvements related to time-based fields in Kogito since version 1.18, see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-6756. Would recommend upgrading if you're using an older version.