# Migration of custom spring boot starter to quarkus

Tags: spring-boot, migration, quarkus

Do you know, how to use customized spring boot starter in quarkus. We have created a few spring boot starters for existing application. Now trying to migrate this app to quarkus. Beans defined in this spring boot starters are not scanned. I configured quakus.index- dependency.name but no luck

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/55513502/2504224?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @geoand yes i followed that post. I added beans.xml, jandex plugin and defined quarkus- index- dependency property in properties file. Most of the bean scan issues are resolved. But beans defined.in custom Spring boot Starter jars are not recognised. It is good if I get some idea on how to migrate a custom spring boot starter to quarkus?