# Injected Bean is null in my quarkus extension

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi, quarkus

I have a quite simple quarkus extension which defines a ContainerRequestFilter to filter authentication and add data to a custom AuthenticationContext.

Here is my code:

`runtime/AuthenticationContext.java`

```
public interface AuthenticationContext {
  User getCurrentUser();
}
```

`runtime/AuthenticationContextImpl.java`

```
@RequestScoped
public class AuthenticationContextImpl implements AuthenticationContext {
    private User user;

    @Override
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

`runtime/MyFilter.java`

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter  {

  @Inject
  AuthenticationContextImpl authCtx;

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext){

    // doing some stuff like retrieving the user from the request Context
    // ...

    authCtx.setCurrentUser(retrievedUser)
    
  }
}
```

`deployment/MyProcessor.java`:

```
class MyProcessor {

  //... Some stuff

  @BuildStep
  AdditionalBeanBuildItem createContext() {
      return new AdditionalBeanBuildItem(AuthenticationContextImpl.class);
  }
}
```

I have a Null Pointer Exception in `authCtx.setCurrentUser(retrievedUser)` call (authCtx is never injected)

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you "indexed" the `runtime` module of you dependency (using one of the methods described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that thread. I was sure that I did not need to index runtime since it would be indexed by default in an extension. I added the empty beans.xml and all is okay. Thanks again

Comment: Great to hear! I added this as an answer, please accept it so future readers can easily find the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing the `runtime` module of the extension fixes the problem.
There are multiple ways to do that as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224