# Override beans from an external library (Quarkus)

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I want to override a bean that's used by Quarkus to disable authentication/authorization.

With the following implementation, it works that REST endpoints can be configured at start time to not be secured:

```bash
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomOidcAuthController extends TestAuthController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomOidcAuthController.class);

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.oidc.enabled", defaultValue = "false")
    boolean quarkusOidcEnabled;

    @PostConstruct
    public void check() {
        LOGGER.info("isAuthorizationEnabled(): " + isAuthorizationEnabled());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthorizationEnabled() {
        return quarkusOidcEnabled;
    }
}
```

This is with the Bean residing in the same Quarkus module.

However, I want to externalize this class into a separate library and if I do this, it no longer works.

Noteworthy:

1. Yes, the `@Priority` of my bean (1) is higher than the default (3000)
2. The beans are discovered, if I explicitly inject them.
3. They are however not used, if I inject the subtype that Quarkus uses internally (either `TestAuthController` or `AuthorizationController`).

   - Therefore the endpoints are always secured
   - As can be seen here from the IntelliJ debugger [image]
4. Currently I have an empty `beans.xml`, but with building a Jandex Index I also observe the same behavior (related [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module/55513723#55513723))
5. I can get the behavior I want, if I use `quarkus.arc.selected-alternatives=com.xxx.CustomOidcAuthController`, however this is not preferable, since each Service using the library would need to configure this and this will certainly cause problems, because it can be easily forgotten.

Comment: related: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-integration#additional_bean_build_item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the priority of the [TestAuthController](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/test-framework/security/src/main/java/io/quarkus/test/security/TestAuthController.java#L13) is indeed `3000` and therefore it takes precedence. Injection of `CustomOidcAuthController` works because there's no other bean that has `CustomOidcAuthController` in its set of bean types.

In other words, it works as expected (and defined by the spec).

Comment: thanks both of you, I was confused because for Interceptors it's the other way around.

But I'm still unsure, why it originally worked in my own module with the exact same setup - but nevertheless, it works now!

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, the @Priority of my bean (1) is higher than the default (3000)

According to CDI specification, an alternative with *highest* priority is selected. See [this part of the CDI 2.0 specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#unsatisfied_and_ambig_dependencies).
[Here is a CDI TCK test](https://github.com/jakartaee/cdi-tck/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/cdi/tck/tests/alternative/selection/SelectedAlternative02Test.java) asserting that higher priority 'wins' during typesafe resolution.

Therefore, your approach is correct and you just need to make sure your custom bean is an alternative with priority value higher than that of `TestAuthController`.

Comment: thanks! At the end I chose Martins answer, because I can only choose one, hope that's okay.