# Quarkus FaaS Maven multimodule project with @Funqy

Tags: maven, quarkus, faas

Im building a maven multimodule project.
Actualy I have to modules. In both of them I create a @Funqy function.

=== Project ===

```
- main
  - module1
    - com.example
      - Function1
  - module2
    - com.example
      - Function2
```

==== The Function1 ===

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Function1{

    @Funq
    public String hello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

==== The Function2 ===

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Function2{

    @Funq
    public String bye(String name) {
        return "Bye" + name;
    }
}
```

When I try to run the application I am expecting both functions to run but only the function from the first module is running. So I can call `localhost:8080/hello?name=myname` but I get NOT_FOUND for `localhost:8080/bye?name=myname`.

That is my first expirience with Funqy-Http and I am not sure what is the problem. But my intention is to create a multimodule maven project, where each module has its own functions (@Funqy).

Comment: Have you followed the advice mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224

Comment: I am not sure if this could apply in this case and how?!

Comment: I mentioned it because in order to annotation discovery to work properly, you need to have setup the multimodule project correctly