# Can the Quarkus Main method be defined in a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I'm building an SDK using [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io). I want to have two main features in the SDK:

1. the SDK provides a high-level API to work with a 3rd party system
2. the SDK makes it possible to build a native image

Using Quarkus in a project directly makes all of that possible. However, I started having some problem when using Quarkus as a transitive dependency. Example source code can be found [here](https://github.com/hariso/quarkus).

Here, `test-sdk` is the SDK itself, providing the API.

`test-parent` is a parent POM, which makes it possible to build a native image.

`test-project` a project which uses `test-parent` and `test-sdk`. I'd like `test-project` to be unaware of Quarkus.

When I run `mvn clean package -Dnative` in `test-project`, a native image is built. However, when I run it, I don't see the expected stdout logs from `test-sdk` [here](https://github.com/hariso/quarkus/blob/main/test-sdk/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java#L17).

When all of this is a single project, I get the expected output. So it looks like `@QuarkusMain` defined in the dependency ([here](https://github.com/hariso/quarkus/blob/main/test-sdk/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java#L8)) doesn't really work.

My question is: are my expectations wrong? Is there a way to make it work this way?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224?

Comment: Yup, and it worked.:) I forgot to mention the results in this question. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @geoand feel free to post your comment as an answer.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can, the only caveat is that you tell Quarkus to "index" that dependency. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224 provides a few different way that can be achieved