# Unable to inject @GrpcClient in quarkus "The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers"

Tags: java, grpc, quarkus, grpc-java

I am trying to create gRPC client in Quarkus. Did everything according to the documentation.

Placed proto files in src/main/proto:
here is the content of the service file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package userinfo.grpc;

import "UserInfoRequest.proto";
import "UserInfoResponse.proto";

service UserInfoService {
  rpc GetUserInfo (UserInfoRequest) returns (UserInfoResponse);
}
```

added to gradle following dependency:

```
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-grpc'
```

When I built the project I saw my gRPC classes generated in

```
<projectFolder>\build\classes\java\quarkus-generated-sources\grpc\userinfo
```

[image]

My service that is using the gRPC client:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@LookupIfProperty(name = "auth.identity-service-enabled", stringValue = "true")
@ApplicationScoped
public class IdentityUserInfoProviderGrpc implements UserInfoProvider {
    @GrpcClient("userInfoService")
    UserInfoService userInfoService;

//business logic
```

The problem is that when I run the application I get:

> Blockquote
> [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type userinfo.grpc.UserInfoService and qualifiers [@Default]
> - java member: <my_package>.userinfo.grpc.IdentityUserInfoProviderGrpc():userInfoService
> - declared on CLASS bean [types=[<my_package>.userinfo.UserInfoProvider, java.lang.Object, <my_package>.userinfo.grpc.IdentityUserInfoProviderGrpc], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=<my_package>.userinfo.grpc.IdentityUserInfoProviderGrpc]
> **The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
> - Bean [class=userinfo.grpc.UserInfoService, qualifiers=[@Any, @io.quarkus.grpc.GrpcClient("userInfoService")]]**

Was trying to add an empty META-INF/beans.xml file in the additional module src/main/resources as well as was trying to add Gradle Jandex plugin, as advised [How to create a Jandex index in Quarkus for classes in a external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module) but did not help.

I have read few times all the documents Quarkus provided but have not found an explanation for this as I am doing everything as described.
Please help resolve this.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange -- as we have plenty of test cases that check / test this.
e.g.

- https://github.com/alesj/quarkus_cl130/blob/stacko1/app/src/main/java/com/alesj/qcl/app/Configuration.java#L28

Open up a GitHub issue on Quarkus GitHub with a reproducer, and I'll have a look ...

Comment: Created reproducer for you:

Comment: https://github.com/denysandriyanov/reproducer

Comment: logged a bug https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35855

Comment: This looks like a Gradle issue on our side ... if I add this pom.xml: https://gist.github.com/alesj/08c78366c471eb799e9f3c16082cd74b ... and run it with Maven ... it works

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Clement found it -- you have a trailing space in your client name.

@GrpcClient("userInfoService ") // <--- see space at the end

vs

The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers: - Bean [class=userinfo.grpc.UserInfoService, qualifiers=[@Any, @io.quarkus.grpc.GrpcClient("userInfoService")]]

Nice catch Clement!

Comment: Hi Alesj, i am afraid it was just a typo when putting down the text here in stackoverflow. So it's not related to issue as it is.
I was trying  both
    @GrpcClient("userInfoService")
    UserInfoService userInfoService;

and 
    @GrpcClient
    UserInfoService userInfoService;