# Unsatisfied dependency for type io.acme.helpers.OAuth2Helper and qualifiers [@Default]

Tags: dependency-injection, quarkus, application-scope

I am trying to use dependency injection from my own library using Quarkus as the main framework and  it's not working out.
When I declare the class inside the project, @Inject works exactly as expected. However if I move the class out to a jar and them include that jar - injection fails. I know the class IS visible by the JVM because if I replace the injection with the call to the constructor - the object is created. That is not my acceptable solution because in that case I would be missing other functionality provided by the injection.
The class I'm injecting IS annotated with @ApplicationScoped

I'm currently out of ideas what I could be mising.

Comment: There are many questions here on StackOverflow, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513502/how-to-create-a-jandex-index-in-quarkus-for-classes-in-a-external-module

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by following these steps:

1. Declare exactly one constructor with @Inject
2. Add quarkus.index-dependency..group-id and artifact-id to application properties
3. Adding Jandex maven plugin