External module bean injection in quarkus
i want to inject bean from an external module(maven project) in a quarkus application but i fetched this jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException:
how to get rid of this
I scan the package where the bean actually located  in application.properties file but it didn't work for me.

Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224 ?

Maybe you already found out, but
you can only inject a Bean if it’s annotated with a scope, like @ApplicationScoped or @SessionScoped.
If not, you can’t inject it and you have to create a new instance.
But what you can do is you can write your own provider that has a private instance of your object and then you can annotate that class with @Singleton or @Applicationscoped to always have the same object. Then you just have to write a getter…

Thanks for contributing an answer! This seems useful, but could you provide a code example of what such a provider might look like? That would make this more useful for future readers struggling with this, I suspect.
