# REST client interface can not be injected in Quarkus kotlin app

Tags: kotlin, resteasy, jsonb, quarkus, microprofile

I tried to add a `quarkus-rest-client` sample for my [post-service](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/tree/master/post-service) which is a simple REST API built with Quarkus.

The java version is working well.

When I added another Kotlin to test the kotlin and Gradle support in Quarkus, it failed, the REST Client interface can not be injected as CDI bean.

The `PostControlloer` is Jaxrs resource to expose an aggregated APIs that combined the original two APIs.

```
@Path("/api")
@RequestScoped
class PostController(@Inject @RestClient val client: PostResourceClient) {

//    @Inject
//    @RestClient
//    lateinit var client: PostServiceClient

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getPosts(@QueryParam("q")
                 q: String,
                 @QueryParam("offset")
                 @DefaultValue("0")
                 offset: Int,
                 @QueryParam("limit")
                 @DefaultValue("10")
                 limit: Int): Response {
        val posts = this.client.getAllPosts(q, offset, limit).entity as List<Post>
        val count = this.client.countAllPosts(q).entity as Long
        return ok(PostPage(posts, count)).build()
    }

}
```

The above two approaches to inject a Bean are failed.

The REST Client interface:

```
@Path("/posts")
@RegisterRestClient
interface PostResourceClient {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getAllPosts(
            @QueryParam("q")
            q: String,
            @QueryParam("offset")
            @DefaultValue("0")
            offset: Int,
            @QueryParam("limit")
            @DefaultValue("10")
            limit: Int
    ): Response

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun countAllPosts(
            @QueryParam("q")
            q: String
    ): Response

}
```

The application config for this Rest Client interface.

```
com.example.PostResourceClient/mp-rest/url=http://localhost:8080
com.example.PostResourceClient/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton
```

The complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/blob/master/post-service-client-kotlin).

Answer (score 4):

Duplicated with [Error to inject some dependency with kotlin + quarkus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458873/error-to-inject-some-dependency-with-kotlin-quarkus) it is a MicroProfile RestClient issue. See the workaround in the original SO answer:

```kotlin
@Inject
@field: RestClient
lateinit internal var countriesService: CountriesService
```

An issue is already openned on MicroProfile RestClient to have a fix for this and tracked on the Quarkus issue traker: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5413